# Does Blender have Smooth Mesh Preview?

Tags: modeling

Autodesk Maya has a mode in which when I press the number 3 key on the keyboard, the polygons appear smooth, with the number of polygons unchanged.

This drawing mode works very fast.

Is there a similar feature in Blender?

For me, Sudivisions of Add Modifier seems to work a little slow on Viewport.

Comment: I don't speak mayan, but maybe you want smooth shading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,as far as I know Blender does not have smooth mesh preview. When I change from Maya to Blender it bothered me as well but soon you will get use to it and you realize you dont need it.

Instead of it you can use subdivision surface modifier and its options to turn it on/off in different modes. It is convenient to let it smooth the object in view port but turn it of when you are in the edit mode.

Shade smooth is kind of the same as smooth normals in Maya

Answer (score 0):

**Maya "3" smooth in Blender?

Yes! You need 2 steps:**

- right click on object and "shade smooth"
- add a subdivision surface modifier, "viewport:2" (2 levels),
  but never Apply it! You created this modifier only for visualization.

Now, if you want to subdivide the mesh, add ANOTHER sub-surf modifer and Apply this one. (not sure if the stack order matters)